# How to store a socket within a list C++

Tags: python, c++, sockets, linked-list

I am aiming to create a linked list where each node contains a socket connection. My issue is finding a data type that can be used to store the socket connection. I did not have this issue in python as lists can store all data types.

In python I could simply do something like:

```
clientSocket, clientAddress = socket.accept()
LIST[]
LIST.append(clientSocket)
```

If I was to create a linked list in C++, each node may look like:

```
Class Node    
{    
public:    
    string username;    
    DATA TYPE socketConn;    
}
```

So my question is, in order to set `socketConn` to equal a socket connection, what data type should be used and if this approach isn't possible, how else could I implement this in a simple manner?

Sorry if I haven't been entirely clear.

Comment: `std::list<Node*>` regarding the bit of code you gave us should work.

Comment: Your Python sample code is not even valid Python. **Also, you almost *never* want to use a linked-list**. Use `std::vector` instead. The data type of a socket is an `int` (except for when using special networking libraries).

Comment: Sockets are just plain `int`s in C/C++.

Comment: So by changing DATA TYPE to int, everything should be good. Cheers @AdamRosenfield

Comment: Why would a linked list not be a good idea? Thanks for the input @dom0

Comment: Linked lists are the exact opposite of what's good for performance on todays (and yesterdays) machines: they store data sprayed over the memory, every access essentially loads a random address, which is almost never cached. You also get a lot of overhead when you just store `int`s. Contrast to `vector`: data store contiguously, almost always cached, little overhead for small data types. In other words: vector usually outperforms list by a vast margin, even for "linked list"ly-operations (random insert/delete).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the std::list (or another container like std::vector) from ST-Library. E.g.:

- `std::vector<Node> / std::list<Node>` or
- `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>`.